# find out the words appeared in a paragraph

Tags: python, regex, string, python-2.7

```
sentence = 'Alice was not a bit hurt, and she jumped up on to her feet in a moment.'
words = ['Alice','jumped','played']
```

I can use the `filter` function in python to find all the elements from `words` shown in `sentence`:

```
print filter(lambda x: x in words,sentence.split())
```

But if there is a space in the elements in `words`, `.split()` function causes mistake:

```
words = ['Alice','jumped up','played']
```

in this case, `'jumped up'` cannot be found in `sentence`, which is incorrect.

Is there a simple method that can deal with the problem (perhaps `re` package can make it?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use regex for this:

```
In [71]: import re

In [72]: words = ['Alice','jumped','played']

In [73]: [w for w in words if re.search(r'\b{}\b'.format(re.escape(w)), sentence)]
Out[73]: ['Alice', 'jumped']

In [74]: words = ['Alice','jumped up','played']

In [75]: [w for w in words if re.search(r'\b{}\b'.format(re.escape(w)), sentence)]
Out[75]: ['Alice', 'jumped up']
```

Comment: +1 for using `re.escape()` otherwise it would be a mess.

Comment: Thank you for your input. It works perfectly. But can you explain a little bit on re.escape()? I guess it aims at handling the space in the string? But \b also includes the space consideration..

Comment: @ChuNan `re.escape` will escape any characters that are considered special by regex, for example `.`, `*` etc..

Comment: @Aशwiniचhaudhary so what would happen if I don't use re.escape? I tried your code without it, it returns all the empty lists, indicating that no match. Is that due to some of the '.' and ' ' characters included?

Comment: @ChuNan For current list of words it will work fine, but if you add any of the special symbols then it won't work. Check out this example:  http://ideone.com/KfLTfl