# How to keep the sequence of regex match result

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

```
sentence = 'Alice was not a bit hurt, and she jumped up on to her feet in a moment.'
words = ['Alice','jumped','played']
```

To match the `sentence` from `words`, I used the code from the answer to my [last post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22862151/find-out-the-words-appeared-in-a-paragraph)

```
[w for w in words if re.search(r'\b{}\b'.format(re.escape(w)), sentence)]
```

which will get me:

```
['Alice', 'jumped']
```

---

Now, if the `words` list is given in another sequence (`words = ['jumped','Alice','played']`), I want to display the matching result in the sequence of their occurrence in `sentence`, i.e., still want:

```
['Alice', 'jumped']
```

instead of

```
['jumped','Alice']
```

How should I modify the code?

Comment: What do you want to get if sentence is 'Alice jumped over Alice'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can built your pattern like this:

```
 pattern = r'\b(?:' + '|'.join(words) + r')\b'
```

and use findall

```
 re.findall(pattern, sentence)
```

to remove duplicates:

```
list(set(re.findall(pattern, sentence)))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This works for me. I'm new to re in python, can you please show me which part in the pattern build-up indicates the sequence of occurrence ?

Comment: @ChuNan: There is no part in the pattern for this, The only thing is that the regex engine proceed the text from left to right. You can give a list of words in any order you want, you will obtain the same result (the order in the sentence)

Comment: so as the sentence shown in comments: Alice jumped over Alice, the same word 'Alice' occurs later replaces the one occurs earlier in re.findall. Then it will be ['jump','Alice'].Is that correct?

Comment: @ChuNan You get `['Alice', 'jumped', 'Alice']` as result.

Comment: @ChuNan: Jerry is right, do you want to avoid duplicates?

Comment: Yes...how to avoid duplicates while still keep the sequence? ([jumped, alice])?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Well, since it seems that the last matches are to be kept, you can drop all the `[::-1]` :)

Comment: Does set() change the order in the list since it keeps the alphabetical order?

Comment: @ChuNan: after some research, Jon Clements seems to know all the methods to remove duplicates and preserve the order. It will be better to accept his answer.

Comment: Oh ok, I have understood the requirements! Thanks @Jerry, you have saved my soul. :)

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Truth is, I didn't know that `set()` returns an unordered list :s

Answer (score 3):

One way is to take the sentence as a base, and filter the words that are in your other list:

```
sentence_words = ['Alice','jumped','played']
words = ['jumped', 'Alice']
in_order = filter(set(words).__contains__, sentence_words)
# ['Alice', 'jumped']
```

Or:

```
word_set = set(words)
in_order = [word for word in sentence_words if word in word_set]
```

Alternatively, you can create a lookup of word->last index seen, and use:

```
lookup = {word: idx for idx, word in enumerate(sentence_words)}
words.sort(key=lookup.__getitem__)
['Alice', 'jumped']
```

And maybe combine the two:

```
new_words = sorted((word for word in words if word in lookup), key=lookup.get)
```